# I am confusing with the concepts: Input and Output devices

Tags: mouse, io

Concepts:

> "An INPUT is data that a computer receives. An OUTPUT is data that a
>   computer sends." (Source: http://www.bbc.co.uk/)

For example I am going to work with a MOUSE (input device). I connect it to my computer (via USB) and I move it (I am sending data to my computer -sending positions-). OK, but when I first connected the mouse to the computer the light mouse turned on, then, is the mouse receiving data from the computer (OUTPUT)? Because when I connected it, the mouse received from the computer "all it is OK, you can work" (I think) so in that moment the mouse was receiving data (OUTPUT) from the computer. Then: is the mouse an input/output device?

**Edit 1:**

A practical case: If I connect a MOUSE in a SMARTPHONE, Could I consider it like INPUT DEVICE or only like mouse?

I said:

> "An INPUT is data that a COMPUTER receives."

Well but: What is a smartphone?

Wikipedia says:

> "A smartphone is a MOBILE PHONE with an advanced mobile operating
>   system which combines features of a personal computer operating system
>   with other features useful for mobile or handheld use."

And When can I consider that something is a computer?

Wikipedia says:

> "...a computer consists of at least one processing element, typically
>   a central processing unit (CPU), and some form of memory..."

Then smartphone concept does not say something like "is a computer", but it fits with computer concept. I'm confusing.

Comment: The mouse is an input device. A wired mouse receives power, not data, from the host computer. Devices can be both.

Comment: The mouse is and input device as far as the user is concerned, however there is a handshake protocol between the two USB devices (PC and mouse in this case) so that they agree about communication speeds and methods as well as the power the mouse is allowed to draw. You can then debate what a USB memory stick is; both input and output device.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers :) . They are very useful.

Answer (score 5):

In simple, functional terms, a mouse (or a keyboard, etc.) is an "input" device to the computer. However, at a practical level any device that uses USB actually communicates in BOTH directions because USB is a rather complex interface that requires sophisticated "handshaking" protocol back and forth between the computer and the peripheral device. Part of that is just figuring out that the USB device is a mouse (or a mouse-like device). It is quite common to see indicator lights on USB devices that indicate when it has power, and then when it has successfully connected (on a logical, functional level) with the computer.

Comment: Even a keyboard (input device) is also an output device, because the computer can drive the three LEDs on in (Caps Lock, Num Lock, Scroll Lock).

Answer (score 0):

You should watch that in a more abstract way.
Mouse is input device because it sends useful data to the computer. It sends movement and button presses. Communication over USB is always bidirectional but still useful data is sent in only one way (to the computer).

Answer (score 0):

- The BBC definition is only from the perspective of the host, which is
  correct if you are looking at this host interface.
- However looking at the mouse device interface, we see it has inputs
  for DC power and a bidirectional USB serial port, which in USB1,2 is
  polled by the mouse to indicate it has data to send. When
  acknowledged, it sends a burst of data.
- IN and OUT always depends on which side of the interface you are "looking from" or in other words perspective, but we generally define interfaces towards the top level or use the term that fits the context or general perspective**, such as the Host Computer in this example.
- The same is true for a UART serial port Rx and TX. Use the Host perspective, not the peripheral.  It is an **out or Tx signal** when coming out from the Host and an **in or Rx signal** when going into the host.
- **Generally we define terms according to the entire system towards the 
  top-level function**, however for lower-level views, it depends on your context. In the *big picture* view, we define certain "peripherals" generally as inputs or outputs, according to this assumed rule.
- Think of doors. For some buildings, there are marked exits (i.e. OUT), (such as emergency exits) and some considered entrances (i.e. IN) and see if this definition makes more sense to you, than BBC's.
- However almost all ports are bidirectional for distinct functions,
  even mic. jacks. They input sound AC signals but output DC bias to
  power the FET buffered condenser mic.
- When the same term IN/OUT must be universal language, such as schematics for host and peripheral, you will see these rules must be followed, if there is a common rule we can avoid this confusion of perspective.

*This is also why English and left to right is used for all schematics, signal names, computer languages and air traffic controllers.*

Comment: This is an important lesson on Electronic Design (at the system & schematic level) and should be promoted not ignored, blocked, put on-hold...

Comment: Thank you :). Then a device is input or output (or both) depending its perspective. I was thinking that all devices were Input and Output (because when I connect it, it sends to the computer an instruction like "ehhh, I am connecting on you" (INPUT) and computer sends to the device an instrucion like "I am going to check you if you work well" (OUTPUT). I THINK). My perspective was wrong (a mix between lower-level and top-level). So the next time that I have doubt about if a device is input or output (in top-level), I will take a look the concept in a general dictionary for example.

Comment: (in top-level perspective) If I connect a MOUSE in a SMARTPHONE, Could I consider it like INPUT DEVICE or only like mouse? I said: "An INPUT is data that a COMPUTER receives.", well but: What is a smartphone? Wikipedia says: "A smartphone is a MOBILE PHONE..." and When can I consider that something is a computer? Wikipedia says: "...a computer consists of at least one processing element, typically a central processing unit (CPU), and some form of memory...". Then smartphone concept doesn't say something like "is a computer", but it fits with computer concept. I'm confusing.